# Where to fulfill a variable to show in view file?

Tags: view, yii

I want to show a dropdown in a form in a Yii project with for items. I know I can use

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'element_id', $Options);
```

in _form.php view file.

Where is the best place to fulfill $options variable ? in which file ? view ? controller ?

Answer (score 11):

The current model is the best option for this purpose because `_form.php` has access to the model and so you can get the data easily. While you can pass data from the controller to `_form.php`, this is more work.

If you want to populate data from the database - for example, you want to show countries from a database table `tbl_countries` - you can write a function in your model to load them:

```
/* Get all countries. */
public function getCountries(){
  $allCountries =  Countries::model()->findAll();
  return CHtml::listData($allCountries, "id", "name")
}
```

This will give you an array with the id numbers as keys and the country names as values. You can then call this function from your view file:

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'element_id', $model->countries());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass your variables from your controller to your view. The data in your variable should come from a model.

Answer (score 0):

$options will be used in more views? if the answer is yes, i would put it on the main controller (the one all your controllers extends) or in the main.php.

If that variable will be used just in one view and regards to clases, ids, the place should be in the same view